# Git log --name-only ignoring some commits

Tags: git

I would like to see the name of files modified in my git history, but not including one commit.

When I use the command: `git log --oneline`, git returns these commits:

[image: git log]

The problem is the commit `0810c44`. This commit because it is a sync commit and it contains a lot of files that were update, but they aren't needed for my current task (It contains a lot of files to synchronize with my local repo).

[image: git commit wiht a lot of files]

I would like to see all name of file changed from the current HEAD to a previous commit (example, `824be3b`), but in a way that the commit  `0810c44` is omitted, how can I do this?

### Git returns as text:

`git log --oneline`

```
9dfe1b9 (HEAD -> tmp_merge_branch) merge
0810c44 retrieved
ff16e9a (1362-bolecode) commerce user permission
3de9164 update flow filter
ec04c9e xml
8851063 add untracked permissions, profiles, etc...
252b039 object
b5db337 add new flows
d9cb7de add B2BCommerceUser Permission Set
f9dc6d2 add diferences from Merge
c0d5f11 remove files
824be3b check before deploy
3212074 restante
69ef93e retrieved
```

```
PS C:\> git log --name-only
commit 9dfe1b9a919c2153f1af56cd21f13d750588b4f6 (HEAD -> tmp_merge_branch)
Author: Me
Date:   Mon Nov 14 16:12:44 2022 -0300

    merge

mergeFolder/classes/BoletoItauController.cls
mergeFolder/classes/RegisterBolecodeTest.cls
mergeFolder/flows/Boleto_Bolecode_Integration.flow
mergeFolder/flows/Boleto_Bolecode_Integration_On_Create.flow
mergeFolder/permissionsets/B2BCommerceUser.permissionset

commit 0810c44fc622d476d54d713b23c993891d7219df
Author: Me
Date:   Mon Nov 14 14:14:42 2022 -0300

    retrieved

mergeFolder/classes/BolecodeService.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BolecodeService.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BolecodeServiceTest.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BolecodeServiceTest.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BolecodeStructure.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BolecodeStructure.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoApiService.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoApiService.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoApiServiceMock.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoApiServiceMock.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoApiServiceTest.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoApiServiceTest.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoBo.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoBo.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoDAO.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoDAO.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoItauController.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoItauController.cls-meta.xml
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoService.cls
mergeFolder/classes/BoletoService.cls-meta.xml
<log with 74 files in total>

commit 9dfe1b9a919c2153f1af56cd21f13d750588b4f6 (HEAD -> tmp_merge_branch)
Author: Me
Date:   Mon Nov 14 16:12:44 2022 -0300

    merge

mergeFolder/classes/BoletoItauController.cls
mergeFolder/classes/RegisterBolecodeTest.cls
mergeFolder/flows/Boleto_Bolecode_Integration.flow
mergeFolder/flows/Boleto_Bolecode_Integration_On_Create.flow
mergeFolder/permissionsets/B2BCommerceUser.permissionset
```

Comment: Is it a merge commit? If it is, try `--no-merges`

Comment: Side note, what you have provided there can be pasted as text instead. Could you do that?

Comment: @eftshift0 It's not a merge :(
I will paste it, hold up just a few seconds!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a simple command for you but here are a couple of "workaround" solutions that should achieve your end goal.

If there aren't that many commits you want, start with a branch that has none of these commits, from there, you could create a new temp branch, and git cherry-pick only the commits you want to see results for, and then run your command for the temp branch.

If there are lots of commits that you want to see results for, and only one that you want to omit, then you could try a similar strategy to above, but create a branch from your current branch with all of the commits on it, and then revert your current commit. Again, this leaves you with a branch of the desired commits - run your command to get the list of files you need, and jump back over to your actual branch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to exclude a single commit from showing up in history using git log, however to list all files changed across several commits you can use `git diff`, and together with reverting the specific commit you should be able to achieve the desired result. Consider the following git history (`git log -p`):

```
commit d9d6084ebc16effd52327fd67b82860d5b9510a3 (main)
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:51:24 2022 +0200

    Added e.txt

diff --git a/e.txt b/e.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d905d9d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/e.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+e

commit 6a3c93aa8746e9d81a7dceefd8f4210bacf1103b
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:52:43 2022 +0200

    Modified d.txt

diff --git a/d.txt b/d.txt
index 4bcfe98..32a8474 100644
--- a/d.txt
+++ b/d.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 d
+modified d

commit 90b7155196a272ca19417b451320a9c66f619f35
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:51:24 2022 +0200

    Added d.txt

diff --git a/d.txt b/d.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..4bcfe98
--- /dev/null
+++ b/d.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+d

commit 8cee8643364631e91f91d36f23d5bf0c3c89354d
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:51:24 2022 +0200

    Added c.txt

diff --git a/c.txt b/c.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f2ad6c7
--- /dev/null
+++ b/c.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+c

commit 1ff08cfde30e9b3ee358ffe1e8ce83d6f08c293b
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:51:24 2022 +0200

    Added b.txt

diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..6178079
--- /dev/null
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+b

commit 36d3284a11b001ecd02d1ab817546bc51ea16cb5
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:51:24 2022 +0200

    Added a.txt

diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..7898192
--- /dev/null
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+a

commit 76da7ed781432d4d7348359665a50baa2df7ac39
Author: micromoses <micromoses>
Date:   Wed Nov 16 21:49:57 2022 +0200

    Initial commit
```

Let's say we want to exclude 2 commits, `6a3c93a` and `8cee864`. We can create a new branch, revert these 2 commits, and run git diff:

```
$ git checkout -b temp_revert
$ git revert 6a3c93aa8746e9d81a7dceefd8f4210bacf1103b
$ git revert 8cee8643364631e91f91d36f23d5bf0c3c89354d
$ git diff --name-only 76da7ed781432d4d7348359665a50baa2df7ac39
a.txt
b.txt
d.txt
e.txt
```

Notice that `c.txt` is removed from the list, but `d.txt` still shows up - because it was modified in commit `90b7155`, which we wanted to include.

While reverting a historic commit may result in conflicts, for the purpose of listing modified files this is not a problem, as it only indicates that the files were modified at a later stage. I wouldn't bother resolving them, I would actually commit the revert without any editing. The end result would still show these files as modified, which is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your needs, but this seems to be against the design of git, there are two important principles:

> ①content tracking. git track the content ， rather than file
>
> ②the hash of the original commit uniquely identifies the state of the
> whole data structure rooted at that commit

It sounds a bit complicated, for example, you want to exclude 0810c44, but your 9dfe1b9 records the modified content, is based on 0810c44, in other words, 9dfe1b9 is 9dfe1b9 because of 0810c44.

And 9dfe1b9 would not be 9dfe1b9 if the contents of 0810c44 were different（or even without 0810c44 as you would expect）but another completely different node (or hash)

So, I understand your need, but it looks unlikely to be solved by git internal command.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a particular set of files that you are never interested in, regardless of by which commit they were changed, you can use a [pathspec expression](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pathspec) that excludes the files:

```
git log --name-only -- ':(exclude)mergeFolder'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rev-list` to list commit hashes, remove target commit from list, and then use `git show` to have a view of each individual commit :

```
git rev-list 824be3b..HEAD |\
  grep -v "^0810c44" |\
  xargs git show --oneline --name-only
```

You can completely remove the mention of any commit (and just have the list of files) by replacing `--oneline` with `--format=""`